# Is there a class to print less pages?

Tags: document-classes

I detect a lot of mistakes **only** when I read the paper printed. For some mysterious reason, I do not see these errors on my screen.

So I used to print a lot, and only to type-check. I use double-sided printing of course but there are still plenty of space wasted ; with `LaTeX` big margins (among other things), I have to print more pages than necessary.

I am wondering if there is a document class designed to save paper by optimizing the space. Perhaps a class which will set the text in several columns, put some minimal margins, reduces space between titles, ... Of course, the result will be ugly but it is just to type-check, not to publish.

I know I could set myself settings in order to achieve exactly what I want. But the idea is to have to change *only* the document class from article or book to this saving paper class when you are at the type-check stage.

Do someone know such class?

Comment: You may be interested in the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) class.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I don't see how `standalone` would help here.

Comment: @tohecz yes `savetrees` is much more relevant you are right!

Comment: please note that `savetrees` will not allow you to check overfull lines, which depend on the dimensions applied by the "final" class file.  in particular, over-dependence on a wide format causes many authors to overlook too-wide display math, where line breaks really should be decided by the author, not by a copyeditor cleaning up a work for publication.  always remember to do a final check; this can usually be done on the screen, with reference to `overfull box` messages in the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about a class for this. However, it would not make much sense, since many in-document elements are a bit class-dependent, as well as many class options wouldn't work.

---

Still, there comes the package [`savetrees`](http://ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) as a rescue. You simply add

```
\usepackage{savetrees}
```

in your preamble, and voilà! the document has less pages! `:)`

To typeset in two-column (which might be a good idea or might not), you can quite always put

```
\twocolumn
```

just after `\begin{document}`, or use the `[twocolumn]` class option, which works with most of the non-proprietary classes.